# Compare two nested json objects rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I am working with rails 3 & using act_as_tree. How can I iterate on nested json so that I can find difference between two nodes?

json that I want to compare looks like this :

```
{    
    "text": "To Do",
    "children": [{
        "text": "Go jogging",
        "children":[]
    }, {
        "text": "Take a nap",
        "children":[]
    }]
 }
```

and

```
 {    
     "text": "To Do",
     "children": [{
         "text": "Climb Everest",
         "children":[]
     }]
 }
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465244/compare-2-json-objects?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*showing the diffs* - i guess you need to deserialize the JSONs into structures, and compare the objects. That seems to me the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

Please, take a look https://rubygems.org/gems/json-compare

It is possible do something to get the diff:

```
require 'yajl'
require 'json-compare'

json1 = File.new('spec/fixtures/twitter-search.json', 'r')
json2 = File.new('spec/fixtures/twitter-search2.json', 'r')
old, new = Yajl::Parser.parse(json1), Yajl::Parser.parse(json2)
result = JsonCompare.get_diff(old, new)
```

Answer (score 1):

As OhadR mentioned, de-serializing and comparing the objects seems to be a viable way.

For that, check this gem:

https://github.com/liufengyun/hashdiff

It even has an [online demo](http://hashdiff.herokuapp.com/) of comparing JSON and YAML structures, and showing the differences.