# what is difference between two object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, difference

Can anyone help me to understand the difference in `obj1` and `obj2` created in two ways in JavaScript? They look the same in the console.

```
var obj1 = { 'name': 'blue', 'shade': 'dark'};
var obj2 = JSON.parse('{"name":"blue","shade":"dark"}');
```

because

```
 (obj1 === obj2)  is false as 
 (obj1 == obj2) is false
```

while in javascript console show as

```
Object {name: "blue", shade: "dark"}
Object {name: "blue", shade: "dark"}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine equality for two JavaScript Objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: A variable that is assigned an object doesn't actually hold the value of the object, but rather a reference to it. 2 separate objects, 2 different references.

Answer (score 3):

While the objects content is the same, you have references to two separate objects, which is why == and === both fail (they check for reference not content).

Answer (score 1):

As ABucin said, javascript checks for references, if you still want to check if two jsons are equal you could try using

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

or check for every key (a bit more complicated but more efficient in the case that the keys are in different orders).

Try reading this:

[Compare 2 json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465244/compare-2-json-objects)

Comment: Don't use the first method, nothing guarantee the order of your object properties.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating an object with obj1 and in obj2 you parsing a JSON object into an object. Since both objects are different (different reference) they are treated as different

You can learn more on this over [here](http://howtonode.org/object-graphs)