# Compare 2 records on screen with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im looking for a way to compare 2 json records on screen. The way i want is that, i want to show these 2 records side by side and mark the matched or unmatched properties.

Is there a library that does it already, and if not, how can i do it ??

**Edit**

My goal is to identify the same/different properties & to show them to users with different styles, rather than comparing the objects as a whole.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare 2 JSON objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465244/compare-2-json-objects)

Comment: Yes agree this is duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone made a jQuery plugin for this - jQuery.PrettyTextDiff.

https://github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function () {
    $("#wrapper tr").prettyTextDiff({
        cleanup: $("#cleanup").is(":checked")
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arnab/YwSVY/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @kaz. Instead of a diff section, is it possible to use colours on "Original" and "Changed" columns ? If the text is different, I can  change all text to red, instead of showing the difference ? And color ir as green if all is same ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick JavaScript function to help you compare the to `JSON` strings.

First, it checks that they have same number of properties, then compares that they have the *same* properties (by name) and then it compares the values.

You may want to tweak the value comparison (to allow for `undefined` or `null`).

Hope it is a good starter for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var so = {}; // stackoverflow, of course.
    so.compare = function (left, right) {

        // parse JSON to JavaScript objects
        var leftObj = JSON.parse(left);
        var rightObj = JSON.parse(right);

        // add object properties to separate arrays. 
        var leftProps = [];
        var rightProps = [];
        for(var p in leftObj) { leftProps.push(p); }
        for(var p in rightObj) { rightProps.push(p); }

        // do they have the same number of properties
        if (leftProps.length != rightProps.length) return false;

        // is every right property found on the left
        for (var r = 0; r < rightProps.length; r++) {
            var prop = rightProps[r];
            if (leftProps.indexOf(prop) < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // is every left property found on the right
        for (var r = 0; r < leftProps.length; r++) {
            var prop = leftProps[r];
            if (rightProps.indexOf(prop) < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // do the values match?
        for (var q = 0; q < leftProps.length; q++) {
            var propname = leftProps[q];
            var leftVal = leftObj[propname];
            var rightVal = rightObj[propname];
            if (leftVal != rightVal) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
</script>
```