# Delete values from JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript arrays (say `newvalue` and `oldvalue`).

These two arrays contain some common values. I want to delete all the values present in `oldvalue` from the array `newvalue`.

Example:say `newvalue` has values 1,2,3,4 and `oldvalue` has values 2,3 I want to delete 2,3 from `newvalue` and `newvalue` should have values 1,4

This has to be done in JavaScript.

consider this as new value

```
[
{"patentid":1,
"Geography":"china",
"type":"utility",
"Assignee":"abc"
},
{"patentid":2,
"Geography":"aus",
"type":"utility",
"Assignee":"abc"
},
{"patentid":3,
"Geography":"aus",
"type":"utility",
"Assignee":"abc"
},
{"patentid":4,
"Geography":"china",
"type":"utility",
"Assignee":"xyz"
}
]


consider this as old value


[{"patentid":3,
"Geography":"aus",
"type":"utility",
"Assignee":"abc"
},
{"patentid":4,
"Geography":"china",
"type":"utility",
"Assignee":"xyz"
}]
```

Now I have to remove objects with patent id 3 and 4 in newvalue

Comment: Are the objects always numbers?

Comment: No..json objects with multiple fields

Comment: Is it _the same_ objects, or do you mean 'similar' objects?

Comment: have a look here - is this your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465244/compare-2-json-objects

Comment: *This has to be done in JavaScript.* What other language did you expect to use?

Comment: How much is it paid ? Just kidding... but that's a way to say "Did you even try yourself ? If yes please show your efforts..."

Comment: angular.forEach(newvalue,function(e){
        angular.forEach(oldvalue,function(f){
         if(e === f)alert("match")})
        
        alert(newvalue[e])
        
       })

Comment: I have tried many ways of this fashion .. but not getting the answer

Comment: Hint: You want to **filter** some values out. Maybe there's a `filter` utility that could help you. Actually, the answers already show you how to use it.

Comment: Don't change the question in the middle of posting it. If you want to change the question, delete the old question, and post a new one.

Comment: I have just given an example

Answer (score 1):

If it actually is *common objects* (that is, o1 === o2 is true), then you can do something like this:

```
var o1 = { id: 1 };
var o2 = { id: 2 };
var o3 = { id: 3 };
var o4 = { id: 4 };

var newvalue = [o1, o2, o3, o4];
var oldvalue = [o2, o3];

newvalue = newvalue.filter(function(e) { return oldvalue.indexOf(e) === -1 });
```

Comment: If they are just 'similar' objects, you will have to define when they 'are the same', and use your own 'indexOf' (or 'contains') to use in your filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve it using `Array.filter` and `Array.indexOf` functions.
Your example could be resolved like this:

```
[1,2,3,4].filter(function(e){ 
  return [2,3].indexOf(e) === -1;
});
```

You can too, use a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) which has a lot of functions to solve these kinds of array manipulation.

Comment: [1,2,3,4].filter(function(e){ return [2,3].indexOf(e) === -1});

Comment: Yes i'm new to stackoverflow now i think i've done it better thanks

Comment: @NithinQ So now that he's correctly answered the original question, he's now supposed to provide another solution for the new version of your question? How many more times do you plan on changing your question? In any case, the principle provided in this answer will work for your revised question. Why don't you accept it and move on.