# How do I compare values of two objects for equality in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have two address objects which has 3 values in each objects.
How do I test it for equality of values in both the objects?

JSON :

```
"address1": {
    "city": "bng",
    "street": "dng",
    "zipcode": "23421"
}

"address2": {
    "city": "chn",
    "street": "as",
    "zipcode": "5645"
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by equality?? be more clear

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465244/compare-2-json-objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var address1 = {"address1": { "city": "bng", "street": "dng", "zipcode": "23421" }};

var address2 = {"address2": { "city": "chn", "street": "as", "zipcode": "5645" }};

var equality = JSON.stringify(address1.address1) != JSON.stringify(address2.address2) ? 'not same' : ' same';

console.log(equality);


var address1 = {"address1": { "city": "bng", "street": "dng", "zipcode": "23421" }};

var address2 = {"address2": { "city": "bng", "street": "dng", "zipcode": "23421" }};

var equality = JSON.stringify(address1.address1) != JSON.stringify(address2.address2) ? 'not same' : ' same';

console.log(equality);
```